# Parse date in the format '2014-09-03T13:13:08Z'

Tags: java, android, date-format, simpledateformat

Can you please help me to parse the date in the format `"2014-09-03T13:13:08Z",`

I have tried the format

```
 public static Date getFormatedDate(String date)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat df  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
        Date dateConverted = new Date();
        try {
            dateConverted = df.parse(date);
        } catch ( ParseException e ) {

        }
        return dateConverted;
    }
```

But it doesn't parse.

Comment: did you not get the date or the required format ?

Comment: What kind of format you want?

Comment: what is the output you r getting?

Comment: do You really use:2014-09-03T13:13:08Z ? Maybe You forgot the whitespace before the Z, it must be : 2014-09-03T13:13:08 Z ?

Comment: dateConverted = new Date(); I have initializing the date object first, and df.parse(date) got parseException so current date will be get.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs no its the same as I given, there is no white space for 'Z'..

Comment: then you should remove the space before Z in your format string?

Answer (score 1):

Your current date format works fine. You need to set Locale

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z",
                                                               Locale.ENGLISH);
```

eg:

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
 Date dateConverted = new Date();
 try {
    dateConverted = df.parse(date);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Error"+e);
 }
 System.out.println(dateConverted);
```

Out put:

```
 Wed Oct 01 12:03:51 IST 2014
```

Comment: let me try this one, Thanks for your help :)